# Is Android Studio tracking usage?

Tags: android, android-studio, open-source

Does anyone know if Android Studio is tracking usage somehow? How can open source project track usage in a reliable way?

Comment: do you mean track usage of memory and cpu ?

Comment: track how many users are using their software

Comment: i.e. how many active android studio developers there are

Comment: sorry im not being clear maybe: is google tracking how many users are using the IDE? what buttons in the IDE are clicking etc? bc its an open source project

Comment: you for sure can read about it in Android Studio privacy policy

Comment: so im not asking about their privacy policy i am asking if they do it in the source code -- if you dont know it s ok

Comment: then you can check it in their soerce code. I don;t think that anybody here ever checked it, and nothing stops you from doing it on your own

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Android Studio does track usage statistics, with permission. There are two places within the Settings menu in Android Studio where you can give consent for analytical data to be sent to JetBrains and Google. The first is at:

- Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Data Sharing

> Help JetBrains improve its products by sending anonymous data about features and plugins used, hardware and software configuration, statistics on types of files, number of files per project, etc.
>
> Please note that this will not include personal data or any sensitive information, such as source code, file names, etc. The data sent complies with the [JetBrains Privacy Policy](https://www.jetbrains.com/company/privacy.html)

This covers general usage of the IDE. The second relates to the Instant Run feature of the Android SDK, and can be found at:

- Build, Execution & Deployment -> Instant Run:

> Log extra info to help Google troubleshoot Instant Run issues. Learn more about [what is logged](https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs?utm_source=android-studio#instant-run-bugs) and our [privacy policy](https://policies.google.com/privacy?hl=en-GB&gl=uk)

Of course, it's your preference as to whether or not you want to contribute to these statistics.

Comment: Thanks -- what if people change the source? Can they change the events being logged? Like sending the wrong version? Is this ok in the open source community?

Comment: The ethics of such a thing is probably too broad to be discussed here. However, if JetBrains analyse the data and see only one client sending out, say, a strange version code, it would likely be dismissed as an outlier given how many people use IntelliJ Idea and Android Studio combined.

Comment: Where is Instant Run option now? I don't see

Comment: Thanks! I disabled this feature in the first time launched Android Studio in the past & now I want to enable it but can't find out in Setting. Thank so much bro :D

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Android Studio tracks your behavior. You can check this out here [image]

Comment: Check this out where?

Comment: @atrocia6 on the screenshot, man

Comment: who vote me down? 

Comment: I apologize, it was my fault - uBlock Origin was blocking the screenshot and link, so I just saw "here" with nothing else. I tried to change the downvote, but SO doesn't let. Again, I'm sorry. Your answer should, though, like Michael Dodd's, note that this tracking is optional.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a live feed of people using your app with crashlytics from fabric, also retention statics , installs , uninstalls and a lot of helpfull data provided by your app.

To implement it please visit this link

https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

here is some pictures of the apps with crashlytics implemented

you can check active users and app statics

[image]

Also take a look at here for more info https://fabric.io/blog/how-to-monitor-app-retention-in-fabric/

Comment: I think OP was talking about the Android Studio IDE itself, not apps.

Comment: sorry, op question is a little confuse haha